# Interpreting PIC Instruction Words

Tags: assembly, pic, cpu-word

I'm a second year Electrical & Computer Engineering student at the UWI. 
I am currently learning the PIC 16F877 Microcontroller and its programming in mainly ASM (with little C) and am confused regarding symbols in its instruction set. Now I understand that instructions may follow varying formats (depending on number of operands, word-size of instruction), however I cannot seem to figure out what the (highlighted) symbols are referring to (yes I understand it's the MSB and LSB of the word, just that I don't know why they're labelled in the way they are, or what they mean)

Section 5 -Table 5-1: Mid-Range MCU Instruction Set, PIC Micro Mid-Range Reference Manual:

[image: Section 5 -Table 5-1: Mid-Range MCU Instruction Set, PIC Micro Mid-Range Reference Manual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that particular document, but I've used the equivalent document for other families of PIC devices. If you look above the table you have highlighted, you should find a section/table describing the meaning of the various shorthand codes used to describe the instruction set (d, f, etc.).

===============

Edit - someone downvoted this answer, so I looked at the document in question. I was wrong: the answer to the question was not above, it was below.

On the page immediately following the one quoted by the OP, in section 5.2, we find figure 5.1 "General Format for Instructions" which explains the meaning of d, f, k, etc.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it was downvoted because you basically said to rtfm, which apparently they already were. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "rtfm" **with** particular part citation is IMO good type of answer (I upvoted, but you can improve the answer by actually quoting here what it says - it's probably fair-use even if the manual is copyright protected), it's more the problem of OP to not read manual properly (then again, sometimes one simply doesn't get it, even if he tries multiple times, and then asking somebody else is better than staying confused).

Answer (score 1):

It's the opcode structure in binary, 14 bits per instruction.

I.e. `ADDWF f, d` for f=127 and d=1 will be encoded as `00 0111 1111 1111` (`07FF` opcode in hexadecimal), the "f" and "d" symbols are the arguments of the instruction (for f=48 and d=0 the ADDWF opcode would be `00 0111 0011 0000` = `0730` in hexadecimal).

The "x" in `CLRW` means probably "anything", the already defined bits are decisively identifying the `CLRW` instruction and the remaining "x" bits are ignored.

I don't know PIC assembly, so I may be wrong with the "x", but I would be super surprised. Is it this CPU with non-8/16/32 word memory structure, addressing memory by 14 bit words? Makes a bit more difficult to quickly asses memory amount, if you are used to 8 bit bytes and count data/memory according to those.

Comment: Just because the instruction words are 14-bit doesn’t mean the memory is organized the same way (Harvard architecture in particular) separates program and data memory, so there’s no reason they need to be a uniform bit size.